# Check website against corporate internet filters

Tags: video, testing

So there are plenty of services to check your website in all browsers. There are many different scenarios to test a website with/without css, with/without javascript, many different screen resolutions and so on.

Is there a way to test a website against known firewall and restriction settings? We are wondering if a vimeo embed and twitter feed are blocked and if so, what they look like blocked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many types of web filtering software with their own lists, and companies are going to turn on and off different categories of sites whichever service they use. Two that I am aware of are [OpenDNS](http://opendns.com) and [Dan's Guardian](http://dansguardian.org). So you're going to have find these services and dig through their blacklists to see what they block.

A quick way of blocking them yourself is to edit your hosts file (if you are on Windows this is `c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`, if Linux, `/etc/hosts`) and put in lines like this

```
127.0.0.1 vimeo.com
127.0.0.1 www.vimeo.com
```

and so on.

The do `ipconfig/flushdns` (windows) or `/etc/rc.d/init.d/nscd restart` (Linux) and restart your browser to see what the pages look like.